# Best way to filter by distribution groups user is in and show assigned to tasks for that group

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest, task-list

Basically, the goal is that there is a task list web part that will use REST services to see what distribution groups a user is a part of and the view will filter based on if any distribution groups the user is assigned to are equal to the 'Assigned To' column.

From research, it seems like there are two main ways to do something like this (with Sharepoint Online/O365; I found similar cases, but nothing exactly like this. If there is a resource with this out there, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction!):

1. Create a custom web part
2. Use a content editor with a list web part and javascript/REST
   services.

I was wondering if one would be better than the other, or if my research is completely wrong and one is not possible. Also, what would be the best way to start this? I'm newer to development and have a rough idea what needs to be done with each piece, but I'm having trouble piecing it all together. Any help would be appreciated! I think I'm leaning towards number two, but again, I'm not sure how all the pieces work together or where to start (besides a content editor with the task list in it).

Thanks!